# Regular Expression Extracting Text from a group

Tags: regex

I have a filename  like this:

```
 0296005_PH3843C5_SEQ_6210_QTY_BILLING_D_DEV_0000000000000183.PS.
```

I needed to break down the name into groups which are separated by a underscore. Which I did like this:

```
(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)(\d{16})(.*)
```

So far so go.

Now I need to extract characters from one of the group for example in group 2 I need the first 3 and 8 decimal *( keep mind they could be characters too )*.

So I had try something like this :

```
 (.*?)_([38]{2})(.*?) _(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)(\d{16})(.*)
```

It didn’t work but if I do this:

```
(.*?)_([PH]{2})(.*?) _(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)(\d{16})(.*)
```

It will pull the **PH** into a group but not the **38** ? So I’m  lost at this point.

Any help would be great

Comment: Because `38` is not at the start of the second group, `PH` is.

Comment: is there any way to extract text from the middle of the group?

Comment: If at that point you had `_(.*?)([38]{2})(.*?)_` it would work. Another point to add, if you just want to match `38` then use `_(.*?)(38)(.*?)_`, at the moment you will match `33`, `38`, `83`, `88`

Comment: Also, side note, using `[^_]*` performs better than `.*?`

Comment: `([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*?)(\d{16})(.*)` uses 42 steps instead of 114 as your original regex does.

Comment: Outstanding! place place this as the answer I be happy to accepted it worked great!

Comment: @Mike added answer :)

Comment: Are you sure you want a regex for this? You might prefer your language's `split()` function.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try the below Regex to match any first 3 char/decimal and one decimal

> (.*?)_([A-Z0-9]{3}[0-9]{1})(.*?)*(.*?)*(.*?)_(.*?)*(.*?)*(.*?)_(.*?)

2. Try the below Regex to match any first 3 char/decimal and one decimal/char

> (.*?)_([A-Z0-9]{3}[A-Z0-9]{1})(.*?)*(.*?)*(.*?)_(.*?)*(.*?)*(.*?)_(.*?)

It will match any 3 letters/digits followed by 1 letter/digit.

3. If your first two letter is a constant like "**PH**" then try the below

> (.*?)_([PH]+[0-9A-Z]{2})(.*?)*(.*?)*(.*?)_(.*?)*(.*?)*(.*?)_(.*?)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are trying to match group2 starting with numbers. If that is the case then you have change the source string such as

0296005_**38**3843C5_SEQ_6210_QTY_BILLING_D_DEV_0000000000000183.PS.

It works, check it out at https://regex101.com/r/zem3vt/1

Answer (score 0):

Using `[^_]*` performs much better in your case than `.*?` since it doesn't backtrack. So changing your original regex from:

```
(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)(\d{16})(.*)
```

to:

```
([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*?)(\d{16})(.*)
```

reduces the number of steps from 114 to 42 for your given string.

The best method might be to actually split your string on `_` and then test the second element to see if it contains `38`. Since you haven't specified a language, I can't help to show how in your language, but most languages employ a `contains` or `indexOf` method that can be used to determine whether or not a substring exists in a string.

Using regex alone, however, this can be accomplished using the following regular expression.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/BSuin6/1)

Ensuring `38` exists in the second part:

```
([^_]*)_([^_]*38[^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*?)(\d{16})(.*)
```

Capturing the `38` in the second part:

```
([^_]*)_([^_]*)(38)([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*?)(\d{16})(.*)
```